# How to scan UINT with width = 2 with fscanf()?

Tags: c++, c, format, scanf

I need to read data like "01", but skip data like just "1".
I tried `fscanf(f, "%2lu ", &ulong)`, but seems that 2 is max length, not fixed.

Yes, i know that i can do it with symbols like %c%c, but it's will be harder for reading code.

What should i do?

Comment: If you have `unsigned long ulong` then `fscanf(f, "%lu", &ulong);`

Comment: read a string (`fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)`), check its length (`strlen(buf) > 2`) and contents (`if (isdigit((unsigned char)buf[0]) && isdigit((unsigned char)buf[1]))`), ...

Comment: Don't use `fscanf`. Read the string with `fgets` and then parse it manually.

Comment: @WeatherVane alright, thanks, but problem is still here

Comment: But what *is* the problem? Please show the input, the output and the expected output, and a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Understood, seems that i should do it hard way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"%n"` conversion specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long n;
    int m1, m2;
    if (sscanf("   123\n", " %n%ld%n", &m1, &n, &m2) != 1) puts("scanf error");
    if (m2 - m1 != 2) puts("error with 123");
    if (sscanf("   12\n", " %n%ld%n", &m1, &n, &m2) != 1) puts("scanf error");
    if (m2 - m1 != 2) puts("error with 12");
    if (sscanf("   1\n", " %n%ld%n", &m1, &n, &m2) != 1) puts("scanf error");
    if (m2 - m1 != 2) puts("error with 1");
    return 0;
}
```

**Better yet**: never use `scanf()` for user input.

Comment: changed code to work with leading whitespace, checked return value of scanf

Comment: seems that this number including %n character too